# Unable to find kube-proxy pod in Openshift 4.14

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-4

I run Openshift with CRC:

```
CRC version: 2.32.0+54a6f9
OpenShift version: 4.14.8
```

I use SDN CNI:

```
[openshift@openshift ~]$ kubectl get pods -A| grep sdn
openshift-sdn                                      sdn-controller-lwtkv                                      2/2     Running            2                 75d
openshift-sdn                                      sdn-djp4v                                                 2/2     Running            2                 75d
```

However I cannot find any `kube-proxy` pod in the cluster:

```
[openshift@openshift 1_internals]$ kubectl get pods -A | grep proxy
[openshift@openshift 1_internals]$
```

Do you know where I can find the `kube-proxy` process please?

Comment: Because it is a single-node environment, openshift local does not use `kube-proxy`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know if there is some documentation about it please?